# Not able to access localhost from Computer IP address

Tags: php, windows, ip, laragon

I am trying to access local project that is running on APP engine. I am using Google App Engine Launcher and its working fine with Postman. I can debug and see results but when I try to access the same app using IP address I get can't "can’t reach this page on edge and same on chrome. This is the only project that is on localhost:80. I have also added an entry into windows hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 192.168.10.10
```

But still I get same response. Is there anything I am missing ?

Comment: Have you tried to create a virtual host?????

Comment: Yes I did tried but that didn't work either. I also added allow from ip in nginx site file but still no result.

Comment: What URL are you using with Postman?

Comment: With postman I am using localhost. IP doesn't work at all. But when I ping from pcs on same network on my IP address I do get success response but for some reason it is not able to communicate with application.